# EC2 security group vs IAM Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the relation between IAM Group and Security group for an EC2 machines?

For example, the following ec2 machine has security group `zfei_profile`, but there no such a thing in the IAM Groups. What "Access Key ID" (and its corresponding Secret Access Key) should be used to access this machine? 
[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is no relation between a security group and an IAM group, they have nothing to do with each other.

### Security Groups

Security groups are like a firewall for your EC2 instances. They determine:

(a) which computers can connect to your EC2 instance, and
(b) on which ports other computers can connect

For example, they say that the world can connect to your http port, or that only your local computer can SSH into the EC2 instance.

The security groups say nothing about which **people** can connect to your EC2 instance.

### IAM Groups

IAM Groups are a way of grouping IAM users and IAM roles. Permissions given to an IAM Group are passed onto their group members (users and roles).

The IAM permissions given to an IAM Group (or IAM user or IAM role) determine which AWS API commands can be executed using the AWS CLI or any of the many AWS SDKs.

In your screenshot, your EC2 instance does not have an IAM Role assigned to it (denoted by the - next to "IAM Role"), so there are no permissions applied to your EC2 instance to be able to execute any AWS commands. If you want to execute AWS commands on your EC2 instance, then you'll have to use an AWS access key ID and AWS secret key to issue those commands (see below).

IAM Groups, users, and roles have nothing to do with accessing your EC2 instance.

### Access Keys IDs and Secret Access Keys

These are used with the AWS CLI and the AWS SDKs to issue commands to the AWS APIs. Each Access Key ID belongs to a particular IAM user.

These have nothing to do with accessing your EC2 instance.

### Key Pair Name

Now we're going to get to what actually has something to do with accessing your EC2 instance.

Each EC2 instance has a Key Pair Name assigned to it. This Key Pair Name determines which private key you need to use to access your EC2 instance.

When the Key Pair Name was created, you would have downloaded a very important .pem file. That .pem file must be used to access your EC2 instance. You would use that .pem file as authorization when you SSH into your EC2 instance.

If you do not have this file, then you cannot access the EC2 instance.

**You cannot get a new copy of the .pem file if it has been lost.**

More information about the Key Pair Name can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

This document also describes a method of accessing your EC2 instance if you have lost your .pem file.

Answer (score 6):

Briefed the terms AWS IAM Groups and AWS Security Groups in simple words :

**Security Groups** : Acts as a virtual firewall that controls traffic to your EC2 instances - i.e., Determines what all IP addresses on specific protocols/prots can access the AWS instances.

**IAM Groups** : Authorizes access to Amazon resources - i.e., Determines what all resources can be accessed by users in your AWS account.